# No proper output for this SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I m using this query to get a result of the difference between the start time and end time of an activity.

```
SELECT end_time, 
       NVL(end_time, (TO_Date(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))),
       (end_time - start_time) * 24 * 60 difference_in_minutes
FROM NCR;
```

NCR is the name of the table. Start time and end time are in date datatype. Where the end time is NULL, I wanted to put the value as current system date and time. I am getting the results for every row except for the ones where the end time is NULL. Please help and guide

Comment: You already know NVL, what's blocking you from using it in the time calculation?

Comment: I don't know. I am getting the value as the current date and time. But I am not getting the difference between the start time and end time after the time calculation is applied. That area is blank

Comment: You mention `end_time` twice in your query. The first time, you do something special if it is null. The second, you don't. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to know the `NVL` function but you're not using it in your calculation.  If you want the `NVL` to be a part of your calculation, it would need to be part of the calculation

```
(nvl(end_time,sysdate) - start_time) * 24 * 60 difference_in_minutes
```

`sysdate` is already a date so it makes no sense to pass it in to `to_date`.  `to_date` doesn't take a date parameter, it only takes a string.  If you pass a `date` to `to_date`, Oracle has to first convert the date to a string using your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.  Then, `to_date` runs with whatever format mask you specified.  At best, you're just converting it back into the same date you started with.  If your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` doesn't match the format mask you're passing in to `to_date`, however, you may get a different date back or you may get an error.

Comment: Thanks a LOT sir. Got the asnwer and understood it well :)